# How to get current time and date in C++?

Tags: c++, date, time, cross-platform

Is there a cross-platform way to get the current date and time in C++?

Comment: If Ockonal is still active, he should change the accepted answer to the C++11 approach. This question still seems to get a lot of views.

Comment: C version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442116/how-to-get-date-and-time-value-in-c-program

Comment: @JSQuareD Even looking at this question now after all this time, I find the C approach better using the `tm` structure. Doesn't the C++11 approach just give the unix timestamp (time since epoch) although the question was about getting the date and time?

Comment: Wow, this question has 1,110,886 views! People really love C++!

Comment: No, they just hate ::std::chrono. It's indecipherable gibberish.

Answer (score 903, accepted):

Since C++ 11 you can use [`std::chrono::system_clock::now()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now)

Example (copied from [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>    

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    // Some computation here
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
 
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
 
    std::cout << "finished computation at " << std::ctime(&end_time)
              << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s"
              << std::endl;
}
```

This should print something like this:

```
finished computation at Mon Oct  2 00:59:08 2017
elapsed time: 1.88232s
```

Comment: This should be upvoted because it's the most portable and easy way in current C++.

Comment: @Johannes, just added mine. At this rate, this should be the top answer by 15 August 2017,  16:31 UTC :-)

Comment: This answer is of very little use without examples of using the obtained value. E.g. how can you print it, get local time, compare with other date/time?

Comment: Examples exist at the linked page.

Comment: how to change the result of `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` to string? not `cout`

Comment: This is the worst answer possible. It makes other c++11 answers a duplicate, and yet it explains nothing, being a 'link only'.

Comment: There's no way to get more to the point than this answer. The OP was asking "Is there a cross-platform way to get the current date and time in C++?" This question gives you exactly this. If you are in doubt about how to get a `string` from `stream`, or how to properly format a `time_point<>`, go ahead and ask another question or google after it.

Comment: I tried using ctime(&end_time) like this and get the following compile error:  error C4996: 'ctime': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using ctime_s instead. Is it standard practice to use ctime_s for compiling on Windows?

Comment: Why isn't there some simple function I can call, which would capture the current local time, with member functions giving me access to all components found in struct tm and some other string conversion functions. All these calls to get basic, common information and add 1900 here, 1 there. Seems absurd.

Comment: @ThermoX Welcome to C++

Comment: This doesn't get you the current time... it gets a duration between two times... How do you just print what the current time is?

Comment: @425nesp The first line - "finished computation at" - is the current time. now() gives the current time (as a time_point: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)

Answer (score 542):

C++ shares its date/time functions with C. The [tm structure](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm) is probably the easiest for a C++ programmer to work with - the following prints today's date:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::time_t t = std::time(0);   // get time now
    std::tm* now = std::localtime(&t);
    std::cout << (now->tm_year + 1900) << '-' 
         << (now->tm_mon + 1) << '-'
         <<  now->tm_mday
         << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Use `ctime()` together with this answer if you want a date string.

Comment: what about deleting the instance of `struct tm` is it possible to just call delete on it?

Comment: @Petr you only need to call delete on memory allocated with new.

Comment: ok but still you get a pointer from localtime() so the structure instance gets allocated on heap or not? which means it doesn't get cleaned unless you do that somehow. I never said use `delete` (c++ keyword) on it, I just thought it should be deleted somehow :) or who is going to do that for you?

Comment: @Petr You don't need to deallocate it because it is allocated statically, see here for this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694365/how-is-the-result-struct-of-localtime-allocated-in-c

Comment: Question: Is there a reason to have the variable 'now' be a pointer?  Why not just say: struct tm now =* localtime( & t );

Comment: @Hard.Core.Coder: Why make an unnecessary copy?

Comment: why need to add 1900 for year and add 1 to month?

Comment: @slier Because `tm_year` counts from 1900 and `tm_mon` has the range [0, 11] by definition. E.g. see the link in the answer.

Comment: One more question - how to do the same for milliseconds?

Comment: `std::time_t t = std::time(0)` is not UTC nor locale... it is epoch (so totally universal). OK, you could say epoch is UTC0, well, yes. So why `std::gmtime(t)` produces wrong UTC time? Is is not really UTC?

Comment: Why do you have the `+ 1900`? (this is not a rhetorical question, I want to learn)

Comment: Use `localtime_s` instead for thread-safe reason

Comment: As I can't Edit this answer (due to the stupid *"Suggested edit que is full"* reason), the output of the above program is *"today's date"* e.g. `2022-9-2`. It doesn't output time!

Comment: When I run this my timestamp looks like this: 

`apISt4pairI5UnitsS4_EdSt4lessIS5_ESaIS3_IKS5_dEEEEEE`

Answer (score 223):

You can try the following cross-platform code to get current date/time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

// Get current date/time, format is YYYY-MM-DD.HH:mm:ss
const std::string currentDateTime() {
    time_t     now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char       buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    // Visit http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime
    // for more information about date/time format
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d.%X", &tstruct);

    return buf;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "currentDateTime()=" << currentDateTime() << std::endl;
    getchar();  // wait for keyboard input
}
```

Output:

```
currentDateTime()=2012-05-06.21:47:59
```

Please visit [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) for more information about date/time format

Comment: Hello. I have a little problem with this "buf" allocation inside the function "currentDateTime()". How is it supposed to persist after the function has returned? Thx.

Comment: The return type is "const std::string", so it is returned by value and then a copy of buffer is made, before releasing it.

Comment: Why return `const` value? That's purposeless.

Comment: plus 1 for cross-platform solution!

Comment: Nowadays `localtime` is deprecated in favor of `localtime_s` with a syntax varying among different C implementations. Microsoft's flavor reads: `errno_t err = localtime_s(&tstruct, &now);`

Answer (score 142):

std C libraries provide [`time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time).
This is seconds from the epoch and can be converted to date and `H:M:S` using standard C functions. **Boost** also has [a time/date library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/date_time.html) that you can check.

```
time_t  timev;
time(&timev);
```

Comment: anon's answer below has a better structure and provides a better example.

Comment: Also, he asked about C++ not C.

Comment: @jterm its ok, C and C++ share the exact same time library, its a matter of different import names and thats it

Answer (score 51):

New answer for an old question:

The question does not specify in what timezone.  There are two reasonable possibilities:

1. In UTC.
2. In the computer's local timezone.

For 1, you can use [this date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) and the following program:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << system_clock::now() << '\n';
}
```

Which just output for me:

```
2015-08-18 22:08:18.944211
```

The date library essentially just adds a streaming operator for `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.  It also adds a lot of other nice functionality, but that is not used in this simple program.

If you prefer 2 (the local time), there is a [timezone library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) that builds on top of the [date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).  Both of these libraries are **open source** and **cross platform**, assuming the compiler supports C++11 or C++14.

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto local = make_zoned(current_zone(), system_clock::now());
    std::cout << local << '\n';
}
```

Which for me just output:

```
2015-08-18 18:08:18.944211 EDT
```

The result type from `make_zoned` is a `date::zoned_time` which is a pairing of a `date::time_zone` and a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.  This pair represents a local time, but can also represent UTC, depending on how you query it.

With the above output, you can see that my computer is currently in a timezone with a UTC offset of -4h, and an abbreviation of EDT.

If some other timezone is desired, that can also be accomplished.  For example to find the current time in Sydney , Australia just change the construction of the variable `local` to:

```
auto local = make_zoned("Australia/Sydney", system_clock::now());
```

And the output changes to:

```
2015-08-19 08:08:18.944211 AEST
```

### Update for C++20

This library is now largely adopted for C++20.  The namespace `date` is gone and everything is in namespace `std::chrono` now.  And use `zoned_time` in place of `make_time`.  Drop the headers `"date.h"` and `"tz.h"` and just use `<chrono>`.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto local = zoned_time{current_zone(), system_clock::now()};
    std::cout << local << '\n';  // 2021-05-03 15:02:44.130182 EDT
}
```

As I write this, partial implementations are just beginning to emerge on some platforms.

Comment: Shouldn't `localtime` give me the time in my timezone?

Comment: Yes, `localtime` will _nearly_ always give you the time in your local timezone to second precision.  Sometimes it will fail because of threadsafety issues, and it will never work for subsecond precision.

Comment: would be cool if you could also provide the update for UTC. Because the obvious `std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now();` fails

Comment: The obvious should work.  Perhaps it hasn't been implemented by your std::lib vendor yet?  http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system.nonmembers#lib:operator%3c%3c,sys_time

Comment: I tried this with gnu++20 and here is the error: "error: ‘zoned_time’ was not declared in this scope"

Comment: Here is the status of gcc implementing C++20 library features: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2020

Answer (score 31):

the C++ standard library does not provide a proper date type. C++ inherits the structs and functions for date and time manipulation from C, along with a couple of date/time input and output functions that take into account localization.

```
// Current date/time based on current system
time_t now = time(0);

// Convert now to tm struct for local timezone
tm* localtm = localtime(&now);
cout << "The local date and time is: " << asctime(localtm) << endl;

// Convert now to tm struct for UTC
tm* gmtm = gmtime(&now);
if (gmtm != NULL) {
cout << "The UTC date and time is: " << asctime(gmtm) << endl;
}
else {
cerr << "Failed to get the UTC date and time" << endl;
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 25):

```
auto time = std::time(nullptr);
std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&time), "%F %T%z"); // ISO 8601 format.
```

Get the current time either using [`std::time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) or [`std::chrono::system_clock::now()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now) (or another [clock type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TrivialClock)).

[`std::put_time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) (C++11) and [`strftime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) (C) offer a lot of formatters to output those times.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto time = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout
        // ISO 8601: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S, e.g. 2017-07-31 00:42:00+0200.
        << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%F %T%z") << '\n'
        // %m/%d/%y, e.g. 07/31/17
        << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%D"); 
}
```

---

The sequence of the formatters matters:

```
std::cout << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%c %A %Z") << std::endl;
// Mon Jul 31 00:00:42 2017 Monday GMT
std::cout << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%Z %c %A") << std::endl;
// GMT Mon Jul 31 00:00:42 2017 Monday
```

The formatters of `strftime()` are similar:

```
char output[100];
if (std::strftime(output, sizeof(output), "%F", std::gmtime(&time))) {
    std::cout << output << '\n'; // %Y-%m-%d, e.g. 2017-07-31
}
```

Often, the capital formatter means "full version" and lowercase means abbreviation (e.g. Y: 2017, y: 17).

---

Locale settings alter the output:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    auto time = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << "undef: " << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%c") << '\n';
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
    std::cout << "en_US: " << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%c") << '\n';
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("en_GB.utf8"));
    std::cout << "en_GB: " << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%c") << '\n';
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("de_DE.utf8"));
    std::cout << "de_DE: " << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%c") << '\n';
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("ja_JP.utf8"));
    std::cout << "ja_JP: " << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%c") << '\n';
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("ru_RU.utf8"));
    std::cout << "ru_RU: " << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%c");        
}
```

Possible output ([Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/903c2c31f8dbcc9a), [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/drNoeH)):

```
undef: Tue Aug  1 08:29:30 2017
en_US: Tue 01 Aug 2017 08:29:30 AM GMT
en_GB: Tue 01 Aug 2017 08:29:30 GMT
de_DE: Di 01 Aug 2017 08:29:30 GMT
ja_JP: 2017年08月01日 08時29分30秒
ru_RU: Вт 01 авг 2017 08:29:30
```

---

I've used [`std::gmtime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/gmtime) for conversion to UTC. [`std::localtime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) is provided to convert to local time.

Heed that [`asctime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/asctime)/[`ctime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime) which were mentioned in other answers are marked as deprecated now and `strftime()` should be preferred.

Comment: `std::put_time()` doesn't work with the output of `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`.

Comment: You can use [`std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/to_time_t) to convert the output of the system clock.

Answer (score 21):

(For fellow googlers)

There is also [Boost::date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.ptime_class) :

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

boost::posix_time::ptime date_time = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
```

Answer (score 14):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  printf ( "Current local time and date: %s", asctime (timeinfo) );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes and you can do so with formatting rules specified by the currently-imbued locale:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

class timefmt
{
public:
    timefmt(std::string fmt)
        : format(fmt) { }

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &, timefmt const &);

private:
    std::string format;
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, timefmt const& mt)
{
    std::ostream::sentry s(os);

    if (s)
    {
        std::time_t t = std::time(0);
        std::tm const* tm = std::localtime(&t);
        std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> out(os);

        std::use_facet<std::time_put<char>>(os.getloc())
            .put(out, os, os.fill(),
                 tm, &mt.format[0], &mt.format[0] + mt.format.size());
    }

    os.width(0);

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << timefmt("%c");
}
```

> Output: `Fri Sep  6 20:33:31 2013`

Comment: This is, IMHO, actually the best answer, since it is the only one that honors locale settings, and because it is programmed with such attention to detail (you don't see `ostream::sentry` that often).

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks. I wouldn't say it's the best though. I've seen better implementations. But I think this suffices for an example :)

Comment: Didn't compile for me. Being a novice I cannot comment on why.

Answer (score 11):

you could use C++ 11 time class:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {

       time_t now = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(chrono::system_clock::now());
       cout << put_time(localtime(&now), "%F %T") <<  endl;
      return 0;
     }
```

out put:

```
2017-08-25 12:30:08
```

Answer (score 8):

There's always the `__TIMESTAMP__` preprocessor macro.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std

void printBuildDateTime () {
    cout << __TIMESTAMP__ << endl;
}

int main() {
    printBuildDateTime();
}
```

example: Sun Apr 13 11:28:08 2014

Comment: This will not work as __TIMESTAMP__ will give the time when the file is created rather than the current time.

Comment: looking back at this, I have no idea why I felt equipped to answer a C++ question

Comment: `__TIMESTAMP__` is a preprocessor macro that expands to current time (at compile time) in the form Ddd Mmm Date hh::mm::ss yyyy.  The `__TIMESTAMP__` macro can be used to provide information about the particular moment a binary was built. Refer: https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__TIMESTAMP__.html

Answer (score 6):

## std::ctime

Why was [ctime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime) only mentioned in the comments so far?

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << std::ctime(&result);
}
```

Output

`Tue Dec 27 17:21:29 2011`

Comment: C4996 'ctime': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using ctime_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following *code* to get the *current system date* and *time* in *C++* :

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <time.h> //It may be #include <ctime> or any other header file depending upon
                     // compiler or IDE you're using 
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
       // current date/time based on current system
       time_t now = time(0);

       // convert now to string form
       string dt = ctime(&now);

       cout << "The local date and time is: " << dt << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

**PS:** *Visit [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_date_time.htm) site for more information.*

Answer (score 4):

You can also directly use `ctime()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time ( &rawtime );
  printf ( "Current local time and date: %s", ctime (&rawtime) );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: in VS2012 i have to add `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` before include to make program compiles

Answer (score 4):

I found this link pretty useful for my implementation:
[C++ Date and Time](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_date_time.htm)

Here's the code I use in my implementation, to get a clear "YYYYMMDD HHMMSS" output format. The param in is for switching between UTC and local time. You can easily modify my code to suite your need.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

/**
 * This function gets the current date time
 * @param useLocalTime true if want to use local time, default to false (UTC)
 * @return current datetime in the format of "YYYYMMDD HHMMSS"
 */

string getCurrentDateTime(bool useLocalTime) {
    stringstream currentDateTime;
    // current date/time based on current system
    time_t ttNow = time(0);
    tm * ptmNow;

    if (useLocalTime)
        ptmNow = localtime(&ttNow);
    else
        ptmNow = gmtime(&ttNow);

    currentDateTime << 1900 + ptmNow->tm_year;

    //month
    if (ptmNow->tm_mon < 9)
        //Fill in the leading 0 if less than 10
        currentDateTime << "0" << 1 + ptmNow->tm_mon;
    else
        currentDateTime << (1 + ptmNow->tm_mon);

    //day
    if (ptmNow->tm_mday < 10)
        currentDateTime << "0" << ptmNow->tm_mday << " ";
    else
        currentDateTime <<  ptmNow->tm_mday << " ";

    //hour
    if (ptmNow->tm_hour < 10)
        currentDateTime << "0" << ptmNow->tm_hour;
    else
        currentDateTime << ptmNow->tm_hour;

    //min
    if (ptmNow->tm_min < 10)
        currentDateTime << "0" << ptmNow->tm_min;
    else
        currentDateTime << ptmNow->tm_min;

    //sec
    if (ptmNow->tm_sec < 10)
        currentDateTime << "0" << ptmNow->tm_sec;
    else
        currentDateTime << ptmNow->tm_sec;


    return currentDateTime.str();
}
```

Output (UTC, EST):

```
20161123 000454
20161122 190454
```

Comment: Why did you ask if the `ptmNow->tm_day < 9` and not `<10`?

Comment: I want a day (say day X) less than 9 to be 0X (i.e. 1 -> 01, 9 -> 09) to fill up the space, in order to match our design. Day 10 can simply be 10 in the string.

Comment: So you need to ask if it's `<=9` because you want to include also 9.

Comment: Note I have a `1+` in the code. Day/Month starts at 0.

Comment: month start at 0, but day start at 1!

Comment: Yes you are correct. Then just change <9 to <=9 or <10, and remove the +1 at day.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the non-deprecated modern C++ solution for getting a timestamp as a `std::string` for use with e.g. filenames:

```
std::string get_file_timestamp()
{
    const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    const auto in_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);

    std::stringstream output_stream;

    struct tm time_info;
    const auto errno_value = localtime_s(&time_info, &in_time_t);
    if(errno_value != 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("localtime_s() failed: " + std::to_string(errno_value));
    }

    output_stream << std::put_time(&time_info, "%Y-%m-%d.%H_%M_%S");
    return output_stream.str();
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer. It integrates formatting and does not show unsafe errors or buffer overrun warnings like others.

Comment: @Gru: Thanks, yeah, I'm not a fan of old school code full of warnings by state of the art IDEs and code analyzers lol

Answer (score 3):

This works with G++ I'm not sure if this helps you. 
Program output:

```
The current time is 11:43:41 am
The current date is 6-18-2015 June Wednesday 
Day of month is 17 and the Month of year is 6,
also the day of year is 167 & our Weekday is 3.
The current year is 2015.
```

Code :

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

const std::string currentTime() {
time_t now = time(0);
struct tm tstruct;
char buf[80];
tstruct = *localtime(&now);
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%H:%M:%S %P", &tstruct);
return buf;
}

const std::string currentDate() {
time_t now = time(0);
struct tm tstruct;
char buf[80];
tstruct = *localtime(&now);
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%B %A ", &tstruct);
return buf;
}

int main() {
    cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H"; 
std:cout << "The current time is " << currentTime() << std::endl;
    time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
    cout << "The current date is " << now->tm_mon + 1 << '-' 
         << (now->tm_mday  + 1) << '-'
         <<  (now->tm_year + 1900) 
         << " " << currentDate() << endl; 

 cout << "Day of month is " << (now->tm_mday) 
      << " and the Month of year is " << (now->tm_mon)+1 << "," << endl;
    cout << "also the day of year is " << (now->tm_yday) 
         << " & our Weekday is " << (now->tm_wday) << "." << endl;
    cout << "The current year is " << (now->tm_year)+1900 << "." 
         << endl;
 return 0;  
}
```

Comment: This is a good example, but the line 'strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%H:%M:%S %P", &tstruct);' must have the %P converted to %p (the latest one is standard, the upper case one causes an assertion in MSVC 2015).

Answer (score 3):

This compiled for me on Linux (RHEL) and Windows (x64) targeting g++ and OpenMP:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Reports a time-stamped update to the console; format is:
//       Name: Update: Year-Month-Day_of_Month Hour:Minute:Second
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  [string] strName  :  name of the update object
//  [string] strUpdate:  update descripton
//          
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void ReportTimeStamp(string strName, string strUpdate)
{
    try
    {
        #ifdef _WIN64
            //  Current time
            const time_t tStart = time(0);
            //  Current time structure
            struct tm tmStart;

            localtime_s(&tmStart, &tStart);

            //  Report
            cout << strName << ": " << strUpdate << ": " << (1900 + tmStart.tm_year) << "-" << tmStart.tm_mon << "-" << tmStart.tm_mday << " " << tmStart.tm_hour << ":" << tmStart.tm_min << ":" << tmStart.tm_sec << "\n\n";
        #else
            //  Current time
            const time_t tStart = time(0);
            //  Current time structure
            struct tm* tmStart;

            tmStart = localtime(&tStart);

            //  Report
            cout << strName << ": " << strUpdate << ": " << (1900 + tmStart->tm_year) << "-" << tmStart->tm_mon << "-" << tmStart->tm_mday << " " << tmStart->tm_hour << ":" << tmStart->tm_min << ":" << tmStart->tm_sec << "\n\n";
        #endif

    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        cout << "ERROR [ReportTimeStamp] Exception Code:  " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [ffead-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp) provides multiple utility classes for various tasks, one such class is the [Date](http://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp/source/browse/trunk/ffead-server-unix/include/Date.h) class which provides a lot of features right from Date operations to date arithmetic, there's also a [Timer](http://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp/source/browse/trunk/ffead-server-unix/include/Timer.h) class provided for timing operations. You can have a look at the same.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

This built-in seems to offer a reasonable set of options.

Comment: Sure:
`time_t rawTime;
    time(&rawTime);
    struct tm *timeInfo;
    char buf[80];
    timeInfo = localtime(&rawTime);
    strftime(buf, 80, "%T", timeInfo);`

This particular one just puts the HH:MM:SS.  My first post so I m not sure how to get the code format correct.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

localtime_s() version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t current_time;
  struct tm  local_time;

  time ( &current_time );
  localtime_s(&local_time, &current_time);

  int Year   = local_time.tm_year + 1900;
  int Month  = local_time.tm_mon + 1;
  int Day    = local_time.tm_mday;

  int Hour   = local_time.tm_hour;
  int Min    = local_time.tm_min;
  int Sec    = local_time.tm_sec;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use boost and chrono library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using boost::posix_time::to_iso_extended_string;
using boost::posix_time::from_time_t;
using std::chrono::system_clock;

int main()
{
  auto now = system_clock::now();
  std::cout << to_iso_extended_string(from_time_t(system_clock::to_time_t(now)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
// Ver: C++ 17 
// IDE: Visual Studio
int main() {
    using namespace std; 
    using namespace chrono;
    time_point tp = system_clock::now();
    time_t tt = system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
    cout << "Current time: " << ctime(&tt) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <Windows.h>

void main()
{
     //Following is a structure to store date / time

SYSTEMTIME SystemTime, LocalTime;

    //To get the local time

int loctime = GetLocalTime(&LocalTime);

    //To get the system time

int systime = GetSystemTime(&SystemTime)

}
```

Comment: The question asks for cross-platform.  Windows.h is Windows-specific, and `void main` isn't even standard C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    time_t currentTime = time(NULL);
    tm localTime;
    localtime_s(&localTime, &currentTime);
    int currentM = localTime.tm_mon + 1;
    int currentY = localTime.tm_year +1900;
    int currentD = localTime.tm_mday;
    // Display the current year, month, and day
    cout << "Current Year: " << currentYear << endl;
    cout << "Current Month: " << currentMonth << endl;
    cout << "Current Day: " << currentDay << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I needed a way to insert current date-time at every update of a list.
This seems to work well, simply.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   //initialize variables
    time_t now; 
    //blah..blah
    /*each time I want the updated stamp*/
    now=time(0);cout<<ctime(&now)<<"blah_blah";
}
```

Comment: There are already a lot of answers on this question, including ones showing how to use `time()`, so this answer doesn't add anything new.

Comment: @Jan That and `#include <bits/stdc++.h` is a **HUGE** no-no