# How to get the date and time values in a C program?

Tags: c, datetime

I have something like this:

```
char *current_day, *current_time;
system("date +%F");
system("date +%T");
```

It prints the current day and time in the stdout, but I want to get this output or assign them to the `current_day` and `current_time` variables, so that I can do some processing with those values later on.

```
current_day ==> current day
current_time ==> current time
```

The only solution that I can think of now is to direct the output to some file, and then read the file and then assign the values of date and time to `current_day` and `current_time`. But I think this is not a good way. Is there any other short and elegant way?

Comment: You need to read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) first...

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Use [`time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) and [`localtime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) to get the time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  time_t t = time(NULL);
  struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
  printf("now: %d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
}
```

Comment: When I try to compile, I get this error test.c:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘localtime’ from incompatible pointer type, what should I do ?

Comment: I know it is like this in many examples, but it is really misleading to use "tm" as the name for the tm struct.

Comment: The definition of function time is time_t time(time_t *); what's the difference between the args and return value?

Comment: @Itachi No difference.  If the parameter is non-NULL, then the return value is also stored there; see the [manual page `time(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time).

Comment: interestingly, when I run a small program with that code with `strace` I see that the `/etc/localtime` is opened. If `/etc/localtime` does not exist, it prints the UTC time without calling the `time` syscall.

Comment: A bit of investigation, it seems that my program uses something called `vdso` that replaces some systemcalls with userspace implementation. Running `ldd` on my program shows that it is linked to `linux-vdso.so.1`

Comment: @dafnahaktana: That's correct.  See the [vdso(7) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) for more information on what the vDSO is and how it works.

Answer (score 27):

**`strftime` (C89)**

Martin [mentioned it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1442156/895245), here's an example:

main.c

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    char s[64];
    size_t ret = strftime(s, sizeof(s), "%c", tm);
    assert(ret);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/48010863e62b7540ded892368a46a28b0d4e2f56/c/strftime.c).

Compile and run:

```
gcc -std=c89 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.c
./main.out
```

Sample output:

```
Thu Apr 14 22:39:03 2016
```

The `%c` specifier produces the same format as `ctime`.

One advantage of this function is that it returns the number of bytes written, allowing for better error control in case the generated string is too long:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> Provided  that  the  result string, including the terminating null byte, does not exceed max bytes, strftime() returns the number of bytes (excluding the terminating null byte) placed in the array s.  If the length of the result string (including the terminating null byte) would exceed max bytes, then strftime() returns 0, and the contents of the array are undefined.
>
> Note that the return value 0 does not necessarily indicate an error.  For example, in many locales %p yields an empty string.  An empty format string will likewise yield an empty string.

**`asctime` and `ctime` (C89, deprecated in POSIX 7)**

`asctime` is a convenient way to format a `struct tm`:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    printf("%s", asctime(tm));
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Wed Jun 10 16:10:32 2015
```

And there is also `ctime()` which the standard says is a shortcut for:

```
asctime(localtime())
```

As mentioned [by Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442116/how-to-get-date-and-time-value-in-c-program/30759067#comment1287613_1442156), the format has the shortcoming of not having timezone information.

[POSIX 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/asctime.html) marked those functions as "obsolescent" so they could be removed in future versions:

> The standard developers decided to mark the asctime() and asctime_r() functions obsolescent even though asctime() is in the ISO C standard due to the possibility of buffer overflow. The ISO C standard also provides the strftime() function which can be used to avoid these problems.

C++ version of this question: [How to get current time and date in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-c)

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This `assert` is a bad idea: in Release mode (`-DNDEBUG`), the `strftime` call will just get lost!

Answer (score 19):

```
time_t rawtime;   
time ( &rawtime );
struct tm *timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
```

You can also use [`strftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/) to format the time into a string.

Comment: Or indeed, `ctime()` on the `time_t` value.

Comment: ctime() produces a tatty non-internationalized date/time format.  It is best forgotten about.

Answer (score 6):

> **[To expand on the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442116/how-to-get-the-date-and-time-values-in-a-c-program/1448084#1448084) by [Ori Osherov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/175504/ori-osherov)**

You can use the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) to get the date and time, this method is specific to Windows, but if you are targeting Windows only, or are already using the WinAPI then this is definitly a possibility<sup>1</sup>:

You can get both the time and date by using the **`SYSTEMTIME`** `struct`.  You also need to call one of two functions (either `GetLocalTime()` or `GetSystemTime()`) to fill out the *struct*.

**[`GetLocalTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlocaltime)** will give you the time and date *specific to your time zone*.

**[`GetSystemTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtime)** will give you the time and date *in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)*.

The **[`SYSTEMTIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/f77cdf86-0f97-4a89-b565-95b46fa7d65b)** `struct` has the following members:

`wYear`, `wMonth`, `wDayOfWeek`, `wDay`, `wHour`, `wMinute`, `wSecond` and `wMilliseconds`

You then need to just access the *struct* in the regular way

---

**Actual example code:**

```
#include <windows.h> // use to define SYSTEMTIME , GetLocalTime() and GetSystemTime()
#include <stdio.h> // For printf() (could otherwise use WinAPI equivalent)

int main(void) { // Or any other WinAPI entry point (e.g. WinMain/wmain)

    SYSTEMTIME t; // Declare SYSTEMTIME struct

    GetLocalTime(&t); // Fill out the struct so that it can be used

    // Use GetSystemTime(&t) to get UTC time 

    printf("Year: %d, Month: %d, Day: %d, Hour: %d, Minute:%d, Second: %d, Millisecond: %d", t.wYear, t.wMonth, t.wDay, t.wHour, t.wMinute, t.wSecond, t.wMilliseconds); // Return year, month, day, hour, minute, second and millisecond in that order

    return 0;
}
```

(Coded for simplicity and clarity, see [the original answer for a better formatted method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442116/how-to-get-the-date-and-time-values-in-a-c-program/1448084#1448084))

The output will be something like this:

```
Year: 2018, Month: 11, Day: 24, Hour: 12, Minute:28, Second: 1, Millisecond: 572
```

---

**Useful References:**

All the WinAPI documentation (most already listed above):

- [`GetLocalTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlocaltime)
- [`GetSystemTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtime)
- [`SYSTEMTIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/f77cdf86-0f97-4a89-b565-95b46fa7d65b)
- [Time Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/time-functions)

An extremely good beginners tutorial on this subject by ZetCode:

- https://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/datetime/

Simple operations with datetime on Codeproject:

- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5546/WinAPI-Simple-Operations-with-datetime

---

1: As mentioned in the comments in Ori Osherov's answer ("`Given that OP started with date +%F, they're almost certainly not using Windows. – melpomene Sep 9 at 22:17`") the OP is *not* using Windows,  however since this question has no platform specific tag (nor does it mention anywhere that the answer should be for that particular system), and is one of the top results when Googling "get time in c" both answers belong here, some users searching for an answer to this question may be on Windows and therefore will be useful to them.

Answer (score 2):

Timespec has day of year built in.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.h.html

```
#include <time.h>
int get_day_of_year(){
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
    return tm.tm_yday;
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers given above are good CRT answers, but if you want you can also use the Win32 solution to this. It's almost identical but IMO if you're programming for Windows you might as well just use its API (although I don't know if you are programming in Windows).

```
char* arrDayNames[7] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"}; 
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetLocalTime(&st); // Alternatively use GetSystemTime for the UTC version of the time
printf("The current date and time are: %d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d:%d", st.wDay, st.wMonth, st.wYear, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);
printf("The day is: %s", arrDayNames[st.wDayOfWeek]);
```

Anyway, this is a Windows solution. I hope it will be helpful for you sometime!

Comment: Given that OP started with `date +%F`, they're almost certainly not using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

instead of files use pipes and if u wana use C and not C++ u can use popen like this

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

FILE *fp= popen("date +F","r");
```

and use *fp as a normal file pointer with fgets and all

if u wana use c++ strings, fork a child, invoke the command and then pipe it to the parent.

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   using namespace std;

   string currentday;
   int dependPipe[2];

   pipe(dependPipe);// make the pipe

   if(fork()){//parent
           dup2(dependPipe[0],0);//convert parent's std input to pipe's output
           close(dependPipe[1]);
           getline(cin,currentday);

    } else {//child
        dup2(dependPipe[1],1);//convert child's std output to pipe's input
        close(dependPipe[0]);

        system("date +%F");
    }
```

// make a similar 1 for date +T but really i recommend u stick with stuff in time.h GL

Comment: Calling an external program is overkill (and makes the program more brittle) and makes difficult to do things with the time afterwards (such as adding an offset, for instance). That's precisely what the OP wanted to avoid. And this is "date", not "Date".

Comment: i totally agree but um the guy asked for a way to invoke the command and use its output in his prog, i gave him what he WANTED! and yet i said at the end, stick with time.h cause thats the right thing to do :S i cant see anything wrong with my answer :S n as for "Date" thnx i fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

I was using command line C-compiler to compile these and it completely drove me bonkers as it refused to compile.

For some reason my compiler hated that I was declaring and using the function all in one line.

```
struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);

test.c
test.c(494) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
Compiler Status: 512
```

First declare your variable and then call the function. This is how I did it.

```
char   todayDateStr[100];
time_t rawtime;
struct tm *timeinfo;

time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
strftime(todayDateStr, strlen("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM")+1,"%d-%b-%Y %H:%M",timeinfo);
printf("todayDateStr = %s ... \n", todayDateStr );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

int calcN(struct date d)
{
    int N;
    int f(struct date d);
    int g(int m);

    N = 1461 * f(d) / 4 + 153 * g(d.month) / 5 + d.day;

    if(d.year < 1700 || (d.year == 1700 && d.month < 3))
    {
        printf("Date must be after February 29th, 1700\n");

        return 0;
    }
    else if(d.year < 1800 || (d.year == 1800 && d.month < 3))
        N += 2;
    else if(d.year < 1900 || (d.year == 1900 && d.month < 3))
        N += 1;    

    return N;
}

int f(struct date d)
{
    if(d.month <= 2)
        d.year -= 1;

    return d.year;
}

int g(int m)
{
    if(m <=2)
        m += 13;
    else
        m += 1;
    
    return m;
}

int main(void)
{
    int calcN(struct date d);
    struct date d1, d2;
    int N1, N2;
    time_t t;

    time(&t);
    struct tm *now = localtime(&t);


    d1.month = now->tm_mon + 1;
    d1.day = now->tm_mday;
    d1.year = now->tm_year + 1900;

    printf("Today's date: %02i/%02i/%i\n", d1.month, d1.day, d1.year);

    N1 = calcN(d1);

    printf("Enter birthday (mm dd yyyy): ");
    scanf("%i%i%i", &d2.month, &d2.day, &d2.year);

    N2 = calcN(d2);

    if(N2 == 0)
        return 0;

    printf("Number of days since birthday: %i\n", N1 - N2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *pts; /* pointer to time string */
    time_t now; /* current time */
    char *ctime();
    (void) time(&now);
    printf("%s", ctime(&now));

   return(0);
}
```

Sample output:

```
Sat May 14 19:24:54 2022
```

This is the easiest way. I haven't even used time.h.

**Be advised**: The output produced has a newline at the end.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
printf("%s",__DATE__);
printf("%s",__TIME__);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: These are preprocessor macros, so the value is solve in compile time and it will print the same two values in every execution.