# dos.h for Linux?

Tags: c, linux, header-files

I have a C program which contains `#include <dos.h>` header. It shows a compile time error. I know that the `dos.h` header file is not valid in Linux.

Is there any other equivalent header for `dos.h` in Linux?

Comment: As the name suggests, it is the *DOS* header file, therefore unavailable on Linux. What functionality do you need from `dos.h`?

Comment: For time functions you can refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442116/how-to-get-date-and-time-value-in-c-program

Comment: I had a good chuckle reading this question.  If you want to get the time, try `man 2 time` or `man gettimeofday`.

Comment: I did answer to the question, but I am surprised it is getting such a positive score. In my view, it is a vague question (not well formulated) and the poster could have googled it easily, and don't show any relevant source code, so the question is not a good question on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

dos.h header file is interface to the DOS operating system. They are not portable to operating systems other than DOS (means not works in Linux). Which functionality in dos.h you are going to use?

Comment: @Dhaneesh apparently would like to retrieve the system time.

Comment: For time functions you can refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442116/how-to-get-date-and-time-value-in-c-program

Answer (score 10):

Linux is a Posix/Unix like system, so you should learn the system calls and facilities that you can use. Read the [advanced unix programming](http://basepath.com/aup/) book (or some equivalent; *AUP* is considered a very good book). You can also read [advanced linux programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (even online, a copy is [here](http://richard.esplins.org/static/downloads/linux_book.pdf)). So Linux don't have a `dos.h` header.

You could also type `man 2 intro` to get an [intro](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/intro.2.html) to syscalls, and their list in in [syscalls(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) man page. From an application's point of view [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) are [elementary operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11609768/841108) provided by the [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel).

The [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) provides a big lot of functionality (e.g. standard *C* functions like `malloc` and `fprintf`, and system functions like `fgetpwent` to query user database, etc etc...) above the system calls. Almost every Linux program uses it.

If you care about coding stuff which should be portably runnable (after recompilation) on other similar systems (e.g. MacOSX or FreeBSD) consider following the [Posix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard.

If you want to code a terminal screen application, consider using [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

If you care about graphical interfaces, use a [graphical toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_software_toolkit) like [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) or [Gtk](http://www.gtk.org/); they usually interact with an [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server (and both Qt and Gtk are able to run on some other non Posix systems, e.g. Windows, by providing a common graphical abstraction layer.). Both Gtk and Qt are adding an abstraction layer (Glib and QCore respectively) above system functions and facilities (in particular above the [pthreads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pthreads) standard thread library).

At last, Linux is [free software](http://www.fsf.org/); so you might find interesting to look inside the source code (of a library or utility) that you are using. You could even improve it and contribute to it.

In all these aspects, Linux programming is very different from Windows or DOS.

Don't try to mimic every Windows or Dos function into Linux (e.g. don't ask the equivalent of every `dos.h` function); learn the Posix/Unix way of thinking and coding.

The [time(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/time.7.html) man page tells you a lot about time (various meanings and functions about it) on Linux.

Don't forget to ask warnings from the compiler with `gcc -Wall -Wextra`; as a general rule, improve your source code till you get no warnings.

There cannot be an exact Linux equivalent of `dos.h` because Linux (i.e. Unix or Posix spec) and Windows are systems with different features and concepts. However several free libraries (I mentioned Glib and QCore) are providing common abstractions to fit into Linux and into Windows, so if you want to develop software portable to Windows and to Linux I suggest using these libraries instead (use them both on Windows and on Linux).

<sup>(I also suspect that Microsoft would use legal threats -patent or copyright based- to avoid that free clone of their proprietary `dos.h`, given their monopolistic reputation and their aversion to standards and to free software; I admit I have strong opinions against Microsoft..)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`#include<dos.h>` is not available for Linux
but if you want to use **dos.h** for displaying the time you can use the **system** function and do it like this

prototype -> **system(command);**

```
system("date +%H:%M:%S");
```

if you want your program to sleep for a specific seconds
try this

```
system("sleep 3") //sleep for a 3 seconds
```

or use this

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
```

but you have to include the thread header file `#include<thread>`