# C Program to print Current Time

Tags: c, windows, time

I am learning C program. When try to run the code I am getting error as : [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <time.h>

    void main()
     {

       time_t t;
       time(&t);

       clrscr();

       printf("Today's date and time : %s",ctime(&t));
       getch();

      }
```

Can someone explain me What I am doing wrong here?

I tried this code :

```
 int main()
   {

  printf("Today's date and time : %s \n", gettime());
  return 0;

   }

  char ** gettime() { 

   char * result;

    time_t current_time;
    current_time = time(NULL);
   result = ctime(&current_time);

     return &result; 

   }
```

but still shows me error as : error: called object ‘1’ is not a function 
in current_time = time(NULL); line. What is wrong with the code

Comment: You forgot to include `conio.h`

Comment: That is probably not an error from when you try to run the code, but when you try to link it.  Also, there's probably more to the full error message.

Comment: this line: void main() is not a valid format.  it should be: int main()  And there needs to be a line after that call to getch(): return(0);  also, the printf() format string should end with '\n' so the output buffer gets flushed, so the output will show on the terminal

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673226/how-to-print-time-in-format-2009-08-10-181754-811

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your looking for something like this:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    time_t current_time;
    char* c_time_string;

    current_time = time(NULL);

    /* Convert to local time format. */
    c_time_string = ctime(&current_time);

    printf("Current time is %s", c_time_string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And POSIX recommends `strftime` instead of `asctime` (which is used by `ctime`): http://stackoverflow.com/a/30759067/895245

Answer (score 0):

you need to change  clrscr(); to system(clear).Below is the working version of your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

void main()
 {

   time_t t;
   time(&t);
   system("clear");
   printf("Today's date and time : %s",ctime(&t));

  }
```