# How can I get current date and time in swift with out Foundation

Tags: swift

I am trying to do the equivalent of NSDate() but with out importing Foundation.

Does the Darwin module have a way to do this?

I was looking at this answer but no dice
[How can I get a precise time, for example in milliseconds in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889380/how-can-i-get-a-precise-time-for-example-in-milliseconds-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but the BSD library
function

```
let t = time(nil)
```

gives the number of seconds since the Unix epoch as an integer, so this is almost the same as

```
let t = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

only that the latter returns the time as a `Double` with higher
precision. If you need this higher precision then you could use
`gettimeofday()`:

```
var tv = timeval()
gettimeofday(&tv, nil)
let t = Double(tv.tv_sec) + Double(tv.tv_usec) / Double(USEC_PER_SEC)
```

If you are looking for the time broken down to years, month, days, hours etc according to your local time zone, then use

```
var t = time(nil)
var tmValue = tm()
localtime_r(&t, &tmValue)
let year = tmValue.tm_year + 1900
let month = tmValue.tm_mon + 1
let day = tmValue.tm_mday
let hour = tmValue.tm_hour
// ...
```

`tmValue` is a `struct tm`, and the fields are described in 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/localtime.3.html.

Comment: This is what I am thinking but in swift reaching into c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442116/how-to-get-date-and-time-value-in-c-program