# error C3861: 'getdate': identifier not found

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <exception>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;


void WORKING :: issuebook(void)
{ ...............


    struct date d ;
    getdate(&d);
    d1 = d.da_day ;
    m1 = d.da_mon ;
    y1 = d.da_year ;
```

I have an error C3861: 'getdate': identifier not found. or identifier "getdate" is undefined.
Anyone plz help me to solve it .
Thank you .

Comment: Did you `#include <time.h>` ? Note also that the standard version of [`getdate`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getdate) takes a string, not a `struct time`.

Comment: yes I am use this #include <time.h> . same error give the VS 2012 .

Comment: Did you fix the other error too, i.e. wrong parameter type being passed to `getdate` ?

Comment: yes I fix the all others errors . just 1 error remaing . and i can't solve it . but it can't give me this error wrong parameter type . just give me  (getdate identifier not found) or ( getdate is undefined)

Comment: Please hit the [edit] link and update the question so that it shows the current, fixed version of the code.

Comment: OK - I think I see the problem - you are trying to use an ancient and non-standard `getdate` from the days of Turbo C and DOS (1980s!) - like [here](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/dos.h/getdate). That old non-standard header was `<dos.h>` and it only worked with the long-obsolete Turbo C compiler. Use standard library functions instead.

Comment: ohh yes , but can you plz tell me what standard library functions I use  ?

Comment: it depends on what you want to do - I suggest you start by looking at [`localtime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime). See: [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1442131/253056).