# How to get time from date time

Tags: c, time.h

Is there a function like ctime that will get just the hours, minutes, and seconds as a char*?

I've tried

```
time_t time
struct tm* currtime = localtime(time);
printf("%d:%d:%d", currtime->tm_hour, currtime->tm_min, currtime->tm_sec);
```

but in the case of single digit values it'll print 8:2:5 instead of 08:02:05.

Comment: Research `strftime()` or just `sprintf(buffer, "%02d:%02d:%02d"...`

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442116/how-to-get-date-and-time-value-in-c-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
`
struct timeval cur_time;
gettimeofday(&cur_time, NULL);
char dateTime[10 + 1] = {0};

strftime(dateTime, 10, "%H%M%S", localtime(&cur_time.tv_sec));
`
```

Comment: Just doing `..., localtime(time(NULL));` would be even simpler.

Comment: @alk It would be if it worked.  But it doesn't  Nice job!