# How do I add a string to a struct using a function?

Tags: c, string, struct, char, void

I made a parking system where I entered the information of the vehicles using the void function.
But I don't know how to put the strings into the struct by using void.

And here is my code.
Where is my mistake?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct car {
  char plate[10];
  char model[20];
  char color[10];
};

void main() {

  struct car c[4];

  AddCar(c[0], "43ds43", "ford", "blue");
  ShowCar(c[0]);

  return 0;
}
// I guess my mistake is here
void AddCar(struct car c, char p[10], char m[10], char r[10]) {
  strcpy(c.plate, p);
  strcpy(c.model, m);
  strcpy(c.color, r);
}

void ShowCar(struct car c) {
  printf("Plate: %s   Model: %s  Color: %s\n-------", c.plate, c.model, c.color);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of errors in your code! To address the 'other' ones first:

1. You need to provide *function prototypes* for `AddCar` and `ShowCar` before you use them, or the compiler will assume they return `int` and then complain when it sees the *actual* definitions.
2. Your `main` function (properly) returns `0` but it is declared as `void` - so change it to `int main(...)`.

And the 'real' problem: you are passing your `car` structure to `AddCar` **by value** - which means a copy is made, then passed to the function. Changes to that copy will *not* affect the variable in the calling module (i.e. in `main`). To fix this, you need to pass a *pointer* to the `car` struct, and use the `->` operator (in place of the `.` operator) in that function.

Here's a 'fixed' version of your code, with comments added where I've made significant changes:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct car {
    char plate[10];
    char model[20];
    char color[10];
};

// Add your functions' prototypes before you use them...
void AddCar(struct car *c, char p[10], char m[10], char r[10]);
void ShowCar(struct car c);

int main() // If you return an int, you must declare that you do!
{
    struct car c[4];
    // Here, we pass a pointer to `c[0]` by adding the `&` (address of)...
    AddCar(&c[0], "43ds43", "ford", "blue");
    ShowCar(c[0]);
    return 0;
}

void AddCar(struct car *c, char p[10], char m[10], char r[10])
{                   // ^ To modify a variable, the function needs a POINTER to it!
    strcpy(c->plate, p);
    strcpy(c->model, m);  // For pointers to structures, we can use "->" in place of "."
    strcpy(c->color, r);
}

void ShowCar(struct car c)
{
    printf("Plate: %s   Model: %s  Color: %s\n-------", c.plate, c.model, c.color);
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Also, if I want to add the time inside the struct, how should I write it in void?Thanks for the comment

Comment: @MLHYLMZ What format/type would your time  field take? An integer (number of minutes or seconds) or something else?

Comment: I want add current time in string or integer it does not matter.When I say ShowCar, I want it to write the current time separately.Example: Plate: 12gds43     Model:Toyota    Color:Black     Added time: 22:32

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1442131/10871073) may help you get the time as a string.

Comment: ... you can add a `time_t` member to your `car` structure, set that value in `AddCar`, then format it as described in that answer in the `ShowCar` function.

Answer (score 0):

You're copying `struct car c`. Pass it as pointer:

```
 AddCar(&c[0], "43ds43", "ford", "blue");
 // ...
 void AddCar(struct car *c,char p[10],char m[10],char r[10]) {
    strcpy(c->plate,p);
    strcpy(c->model,m);
    strcpy(c->color,r);
 }
```