# C proggraming - Characters error exporting TXT file

Tags: c, export, export-to-excel, txt

My code export a TXT file which is supposed to be read by a Macro in Excel, but it writes the file name in the wrong way.

The name I assign to the file is something like `Lissajous Figure 08-05-21 15-19-04.txt` (where the numbers refers to the current hour, day, month and year) but when running the code the file name is `Lissajous Figure 08-05-21 15-19-04` with that unknown caracter before the first letter.

I'll let my code below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

//SOURCES
//https://austinrepp.com/how-to-write-to-a-csv-file-in-c/
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442116/how-to-get-the-date-and-time-values-in-a-c-program
//https://austinrepp.com/how-to-write-to-a-csv-file-in-c/

float * genUnitCircle(); 
void genLissajousFigures(float A, float a, float B, float b, float delta);

void genLissajousFigures(float A, float a, float B, float b, float delta){
   FILE * fpointer;
   char fileName[100];
   int i;
   float * circle;

   time_t timer;
   char buffer[26], line[50];
   struct tm* tm_info;

   time(&timer);
   tm_info = localtime(&timer);

   strcat(fileName, "Lissajous Figure ");
   strftime(buffer, 26, "%d-%m-%y %H-%M-%S", tm_info);
   strcat(fileName, buffer);
   strcat(fileName, ".txt");

   fpointer = fopen(fileName, "w+");   

   circle = genUnitCircle();

   for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      fprintf(fpointer, "%3.4f \n", A * sin(a * circle[i]));    
   }
   for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      fprintf(fpointer, "%3.4f \n ", B * sin(b * circle[i] + delta));    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fileName` variable is getting passed to `strcat()`, which expects a valid 0-terminated C string as its first argument, before being initialized as one, causing undefined behavior (manifesting in this case as garbage bytes at the beginning of the string). Use

```
strcpy(fileName, "Lissajous Figure ");
```

instead.