# tinyXml how to create xml

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml++

HI,

I have the following:

```
class pers
{
    public:
      pers();
      std::string name;
      long favourite_number;
      time_t curent_time;
}
```

I would like to create an xml using tinyXml. Here is the `xml:`

```
<data>
<name> me </name>
<favourite_number> 1233336555 </favourite_number> //it's a long number
<curent_time> hour:day:month:year </curent_time>
```

And here is the code:

```
main()
{
    pers *p = new pers();
    pers->name="me";
    pers->favourite_number=12333336555;

    /**/how too print the curent time ?**
    TiXmlDocument doc;
    TiXmlElement * root;
    root = new TiXmlElement( "data" );  
    TiXmlElement * element1 = new TiXmlElement( "name" );  
    root->LinkEndChild( element1); 
    TiXmlText * text1 = new TiXmlText( pers->name );  
    element1->LinkEndChild( text1 ); 
    TiXmlElement * element2 = new TiXmlElement( "favourite_number" );  
    root->LinkEndChild( element2); 
    long d=pers->favourite_number;

    std::ostringstream os;
    os << d;
    std::string buf2=os.str();

   TiXmlText * text2 = new TiXmlText( buf2 );  
   element2->LinkEndChild( text2 );
```

1. How to do this if I want to have the current time in the xml?
2. Isn't there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

So your question basically has nothing to do with XML, nor TinyXml? Next time you might want to simplify your question and give it an appropriate title.

You can either go via [time.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/) and the functionality provided in there or use something like [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/date_time.html). Something which was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/get-current-time-and-date) as well.