# How to get current date and time?

Tags: c++, time

How to get current date d/m/y. I need that they have 3 different variables not one, for example `day=d; month=m; year=y;`.

Comment: What have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/c-get-current-time-and-date

Comment: @Fredrik, it's simpler to ask than do research.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For linux, you would use the ['localtime'](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) function.

```
#include <time.h>

time_t theTime = time(NULL);
struct tm *aTime = localtime(&theTime);

int day = aTime->tm_mday;
int month = aTime->tm_mon + 1; // Month is 0 - 11, add 1 to get a jan-dec 1-12 concept
int year = aTime->tm_year + 1900; // Year is # years since 1900
```

Comment: Did you mean localtime(&time(NULL)); ?

Comment: I corrected the answer as it would not compile as-is. You can't an rvalue by pointer (i.e. just a number) so you need to put it into a variable first

Answer (score 17):

Here is the `chrono` way (C++0x) - see it live on **http://ideone.com/yFm9P**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef std::chrono::system_clock Clock;

int main()
{
    auto now = Clock::now();
    std::time_t now_c = Clock::to_time_t(now);
    struct tm *parts = std::localtime(&now_c);

    std::cout << 1900 + parts->tm_year  << std::endl;
    std::cout << 1    + parts->tm_mon   << std::endl;
    std::cout <<        parts->tm_mday  << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: posted the working example live on http://ideone.com/yFm9P

Comment: @PaoloM that header is required for [`std::time_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t)

Comment: Sorry, under gcc 4.8 it compiles without `<ctime>`. It gets included by `<chrono>` for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/) library provide such functionnality.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/c-get-current-time-and-date). It is an other post that might help you out depending on your platform.

Comment: `#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
    cout << (now->tm_year + 1900) << '-' 
         << (now->tm_mon + 1) << '-'
         <<  now->tm_mday
         << endl;
}
` Thanks