# Adding times to logs

Tags: c++, logging, stderr, sfml

I'm using SFML 1.6 to make a game, and sometimes, there will be errors, and when users run the game, I don't want the console showing up, so I redirected `stderr` (which SFML uses to log errors apparently) to a file named after the current date. So if there's an error, the users can just check the logs. Now I also want to put the times before each log, so the log file will look like this:

```
12:34:17 CDT
failed to load image "sprite.png"

12:35:01 CDT
failed to load file "font.ttf"
```

Is there a way to "tack on" the current time to any output to get the results shown above?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention, the SFML library is the one that logs most of the errors, I want to tack on the time as it leaves the application, so to speak. Kind of like a tollbooth, except anything leaving gets a time prepended. I know how to get the time as a string, and I'm not the one calling printf or any other function like it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/c-get-current-time-and-date

Comment: I can already get the time as a string, i need to prefix every stderr log with it though...

Comment: Have you had a look at fprintf? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fprintf/

Comment: stderr can be used as an argument for any function that expects an output stream as one of its parameters.

Comment: That's quite a surprising idea (from SFML). It basically prevents you to separate their logging from regular error output should you wish to...

Answer (score 2):

You can do better than a simple redirection: you can actually interpose code of your own between the incoming stream of characters and the writing to the file.

The basic idea is to derive a class from `filebuf`, to control the characters that are put.

You have two strategies:

- the easy way is that each time you read a `\n` character you set a flag, and on the first `put` afterward you insert your timestamp (and unset the flag)
- the hard way is that you bufferize the output until a `\n` character is met, at which point you format your timestamp and then flush the buffer (up until `\n`)

If we consider that there is not much time between the start and end of formatting of each line, the easy way should work reliably enough.

I think that overriding `xsputn` should be enough to get the work done.

Comment: +1 This advice matches with their documentation: http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/group__system.php#func-members
(though sf::err() is from SFML 2.0, I'm sure it works the same with std::cerr)

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the function doing the actual printing, then yes (I recommend you look up the functions `time`, `ctime`, `localtime` and `strftime`). If you can *not* modify the function, then no.

Comment: i think it happens in their libraries, and i DONT want to touch those and risk breaking something...