# Timer, saving events to an array in C++

Tags: c++

I want to create a timer in C++ and when a user presses a button, the program logs to an array the name of the button pressed and the time it was pressed.

Later, I want to be able to 'play back' what the user has done, eg. starting a timer, and simulating the button presses at the correctly logged time in the array.

Where would the best place to start be? Is there a timer function in C++?

Comment: That is time stamps. How am I supposed to play those back?

Comment: Sorry i think i misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
struct ButtonEvent{
     EventInfo ei;
     std::chrono::milliseconds time_stamp;

};

struct Recorder{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start_time_;


    std::deque<ButtonEvent> events_;

void StartRecording(){
    start_time_ = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
}

    void HandleEvent(EventInfo e){
        ButtonEvent be;
        be.time_stamp = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() -  start_time_);
        be.ei = e;
        events_.push_back(be);
    }

    void Playback(){
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point 
        playback_time =std::chrono::steady_clock::now() ;
        while(events_.size()){
              std::chrono::milliseconds ts = 
                 std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - playback_time);
             if(events_.front().time_stamp <= ts){
             EventInfo e = events_.front().ei;
             // playback the event
             //...

             events_.pop_front();
        }

        // Some kind of sleep if you want

    }


}
```

};

Where EventInfo is some structure that has the info necessary to play back the event

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to [How to get current time and date in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/c-get-current-time-and-date) . The standard library for time in C++ is ctime which comes from C.  As that answer mentions, use boost if you want a more modern date time API http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html