# Auto download file from FTP and check against existing file

Tags: c++, vb.net, ftp, compare

I have an internal company need to create some sort of application which does the following daily at a specific time:

1. connects to our company's internal ftp url (not a secure url)
2. downloads a file with a specific file name
3. checks the newly downloaded file with the file downloaded the day before
4. throws an error if the file is the same or else displays a message saying all is good (or sends an email or something with that notification)

That's it. All i need to do is to check and make sure the file on the ftp is different from the day before.

Can anyone recommend an easy way of doing this? I've tried googling for a solution and not quite finding a straight answer.

I've been out of programming for the last 8 years but I still remember visual basic 6.0 and visual c++.

Please guide / suggest as you see fit.

Thank you :)

Comment: Get an FTP client library (google it, there are plenty of them), read its documentation (it should be a very simple one), read up on how FTP commands are formed and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

For vc++:
You could use any ftp client library for downloading a file. Take a look at this SO question which could be useful to you [C++ FTP Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244095/c-ftp-library) . Then you need a proper way to chech the time. I think your program might need to run at statup and check for the system time at a specific interval if the time is due then download the file. For this you can take alook at this question [How to get current time and date in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-c) . Finally there are numerous ways for comparing the file and outputing the result, for starters is suggest you use the std.