# Implementation of locale formatted time output

Tags: c++, datetime, locale, overloading

I am trying to implement in a program the code for printing locale time in C++ given in [How to get current time and date in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-c/18666245#18666245)  .

I made some correction to adapt the code to my header but it still gives me an error "Method 'put' could not be resolved". I am novice so I could not find an answer. I am on Eclipse. I have set the scalability number of the editor to 50000. Also the file has another class between inclusions and code.

The code is this:

```
#ifndef LISTA_H_
#define LISTA_H_

#include "nodel.h"
#include "hntable.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class timefmt
{
public:
    timefmt(std::string fmt)
        : format(fmt) { }

    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &, timefmt const &);

private:
    string format;
};


std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, timefmt const& mt)
{
    std::ostream::sentry s(os);

    if (s)
    {
        time_t t = time(0);
        tm const* tm = localtime(&t);
        ostreambuf_iterator<char> out(os);

        use_facet<time_put<char>>(os.getloc())
            .put(out, os, os.fill(),
                 tm, &mt.format[0], &mt.format[0] + mt.format.size());
    }

    os.width(0);

    return os;
}

#endif /* LISTA_H_ */
```

Edit: If I include "locale" the error previously show is solved but:
multiple definition of `operator<<(std::ostream&, timefmt const&)' .
Any hints about this?

Comment: You have many errors on your code.....are you posting ALL of your code? I don't see "tm" type defintion/declaration by just glancing at it.

Comment: @Miguel `tm` is [defined in the standard library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I didn't know that even existed I thought it was a user-defined type that he forgot to declare. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `#include <locale>`, and your code [compiles](http://ideone.com/trWhQD)

Comment: Now it has no problem with put but "multiple definition of `operator<<(std::ostream&, timefmt const&)'". Any hint about this?

Comment: Don't define functions in headers. Declare them there, define them in exactly one source file.