# How to make program run at same speed on different computers?

Tags: c++, performance, windows-7

Bit of a noob here.
I'm making a basic Pong clone game in C++ with SFML, but when I run the .exe on other computers the program runs (for most other PCs) slower.
I've used Java before and used this way to regulate the amount of updates per second:

```
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
    double delta = 0;

    while(running)
        {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1)
                {
                    update();
                    delta--;
                }
        render();
        }                               
    }
```

I was planning on using this, but does C++ have anything like Java's System.nanoTime() method?
How else could I make sure that my programs run at (or at least appear to run at) the same speed on different computers?

-Windows 7, VS2010.

Comment: Some reading material for you: [deWiTTERS Game Loop](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/). And some more: [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono).

Comment: [SFML has time handling facilities...](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/system-time.php)

Comment: @JosephMansfield how did you post two links in one comment?

Comment: @Gasim Is that not possible?

Comment: 10 minutes ago, my second link didn't get formatted into a link. Maybe it has something to do with reputation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the C++11 `<chrono>` header with all it's time functions or since you're already using SFML, you can use its functions directly. There's `window.setFramerateLimit(uint)`, which uses `sleep()` to reduce the CPU usage if possible, however `sleep()` always has some inaccuracy. Then there's `window.setVerticalSyncEnabeled(bool)`, which will (de-)activate VSync. It's the way you most likely want to go, keep in mind however that VSync can be forced off by the driver.

For keeping track of the time you can use `sf::Time` and `sf::Clock`. `sf::Time` is just a container that holds a certain timespan and can be easily converted to seconds, milliseconds  and microseconds. `sf::Clock` can only be restarted, they are not stop watches (see [here](http://www.bromeon.ch/libraries/thor/v2.0/doc/classthor_1_1_stop_watch.html) if you need such a functionality), but you can retrieved that time passed as `sf::Time` object, since the clock was reset last.

Don't forget to go through the SFML [tutorials](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/) and the [documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/), they contain about anything you'd want to know about SFML.

Btw. working with nanoseconds is more of an illusion than anything, it's not very accurate and if your game would need such a small resolution, your game logic might need some optimizing.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, you could try [`timeGetTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The former is much easier to digest, although slightly less accurate.

For non-Windows folk, you could use [`clock`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) or [`time`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-c).  There are tons of others out there, too.