# Cannot create a file name including date and time in C++

Tags: c++, file, stream, ofstream

I have this:

```
std::ofstream * file = new std::ofstream();
if (seperator == 1) file->open("C:/Users/Max/Desktop/Sparade filer/" + name + ".txt");
else 
{
    std::string stamp = (std::string)__DATE__ + " : " + (std::string)__TIME__;
    file->open("C:/Users/*directory*/" + name + " - " + stamp + ".txt");
}

*file << data;
delete file;
```

**directory* is of course something else*

But for some reason, only the things within the if-block works. The filename doesn't exist, so a new file is created completely based on the variables (`name` is equal to "my save" in this case). So if I set my seperator to `1`, I get a new file in my directory called "my file.txt", by which means that it functions properly. However as soon as I set it to something else, I don't get anything. I've checked several times, and the else block is entered, and the first argument of `ofstream::open()` is a valid string.

Help would be gladly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A filename is not allowed to contain character ":".

Comment: Hahaha, if that's really it, then I sure feel stupid :P
I'll try finding a bypass for the dates, and we'll see if it makes any difference. **EDIT:** Removed the time temporarily, and now it works. Thanks a ton! I'll accept the answer in 6 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The **DATE** and **TIME** return the time and date the program was compiled. That's different than the system's date and time. Now if that was what you were looking for then great!!

But if you want your program to stamp the folder with the updated system date and time on every run then I recommend looking at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-c). The answer by TrungTN is the works before me.

I hope that helps!