# How can I get the current system time in C++

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++. While doing a clock program I was wondering how do you get the current system time?

Comment: It's courageous of you to learn c++ at such a young age and I wsih you all the best but this question has been answered several times before and will likely by closed. Please check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-c

Comment: @W.K.S how would you know his age?

Comment: @Mayur: the linked question is quite old, scroll down to see answers for the post C++11 era.

Comment: @JSQuareD check the history/edits of the question

Answer (score 3):

C++ provides the `std::chrono` library to deal with date and time values.

You can get the current system time using [`std::chrono::system_clock::now()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now):

```
auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

---

<sub>The linked reference contains a more complete example.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

std C libraries provide time(). This is seconds from the epoch and can be converted to date and H:M:S using standard C functions. Boost also has a time/date library that you can check.

```
time_t  timev;
time(&timev);
```

Please make sure you are googling/researching before you ask questions..

Comment: why use boost when you can use `std::chrono`?