# Can't open "date-named" file?

Tags: c++, file, date

I have this code which should create & open a file.

**OpenFile():**

```
std::string fileName = GetCurrentDate() +".txt";
std::cout << fileName << std::endl; //debug
m_file.open(fileName);

if (!m_file.is_open()) {
    LOG(0, "ERROR creating log file");
}
```

The log file's name should be the current date. (If I use a hardcoded text like "log.txt" it works.)

**GetCurrentDate():**

```
struct tm newtime;
__time32_t aclock;
_time32(&aclock);
_localtime32_s(&newtime, &aclock);

char buffer[32];
errno_t errNum;
errNum = asctime_s(buffer, 32, &newtime);

if (errNum) {
    printf("Error code: %d", (int)errNum);
}

std::string str = buffer;
//buffer ends with an end line
str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n'), str.end());

return str;
```

The result fileName string is this: `Tue Dec 27 03:29:17 2016.txt`

**Why doesn't it open the file?**

*(extra: isn't there a simpler way of getting current date? Y-M-D is enough for me)*

*(I use Visual Studio which recommended this)*

Comment: You can't use `:` in a filename on Windows. The two `:` in the filename (in the time portion) are making the filename invalid.

Comment: Thanks, you can write an answer if you want to, and I will accept it in the morning, but now I have to sleep :) Thanks again!

Comment: For the extra question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-c