# difference between a date and current date

Tags: c++, date, c++11

I have a 14 day schedule and instead of memorizing it I wrote this. but I don't know how to get the current date in a format that will work for this program. C++11 is preferred but not required

```
#include <iostream>
#include <date.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    auto a = 2012_y/1/24;
    auto b = current date; //I have not figured how to get current date 
    auto c = (sys_days{b} - sys_days{a}).count();
    auto d = c%14
    switch (d) {
    case 1: cout << blank; //blank will be replaced with the schedule
    break;
    case 2: cout << blank;
    break;
    case 3: cout << blank;
    break;
    case 4: cout << blank;
    break;
    case 5: cout << blank;
    break;
    case 6: cout << blank;
    break;
    case 7: cout << blank;
    break;
    case 8: cout << blank;
    break;
    case 9: cout << blank;
    break;
    case 10: cout << blank;
    break;
    case 11: cout << blank;
    break;
    case 12: cout << blank;
    break;
    case 13: cout << blank;
    break;
    case 14: cout << blank;
    break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current time and date in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-c)

Comment: Are you using Howard Hinnant's [date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)? If so, it looks like the test folder contains several cases that do exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using [Howard Hinnant's date/time library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

You can get the current date in terms of a `sys_days` with:

```
auto b = floor<days>(chrono::system_clock::now());
```

This will be the current date in UTC.  If you need it in a specific time zone, you'll need to use the time zone library (tz.h at the same location you found date.h).

If you're using C++17, `floor` can be found in `<chrono>`.  Otherwise you can find it in `"date.h"`.