# Adding a timestamp to filenames in C++

Tags: c++

```
std::ofstream myFile ("report.csv");
```

So in my folder, I will get the file as "report.csv"

How can I add a timestamp to the file name making it look like
(date)_(time)_report.csv?

I have included...

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std::chrono;
```

I do not wish to add more libraries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27856440/4410376

Comment: Since for whatever reason you don't want to use any other libraries, take a look at `struct tm`

Comment: @Hack06
I have error C4996 coming up

Comment: @jkb I have error C4996 popping up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specify if the timestamp should be UTC (recommended) or just local date-time, here are both ways:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip> // put_time
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream> // stringstream

int main()
{

    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto UTC = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count();

    auto in_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    std::stringstream datetime;
    datetime << std::put_time(std::localtime(&in_time_t), "%Y-%m-%d %X");
    
    // UTC
    std::ofstream myFile1("report_" + std::to_string(UTC) + ".csv");
    // DateTime
    std::ofstream myFile2("report_" + datetime.str() + ".csv");

    return 0;
}
```