# Is there any date-time module in c++

Tags: c++, datetime, c++11, c++17, c++-chrono

Is there any date time module in c++?
I researched a bit in google and came to know about [`<ctime>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ctime) header file but it just went above my head.

Any other thing that can do my work?

Comment: BTW [Boost.Date_Time library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/date_time.html) might help.

Comment: @KaiserKatze: If I'm not mistaken, Boost's DateTime library [hasn't](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/date_time.html) been updated in 15 years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### In the C++ standard: `<chrono>`

**C++11**

Starting with C++11, the standard library contains [date & time utilities, available in the `<chrono>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono), with constructs within the `std::chrono` namespace.

Among these you will find:

- Clocks
- Time points
- Durations
- A flexible [mechanism](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/parse) for parsing date & time values from strings

the library is heavily templated, so that you can use a type of your choice for the raw representation (even floating-point types), and set your own resolution.

Example of use: [How to get current time and date in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/997946/1593077)

Note that `std::chrono` facilities are somewhat-compatible with the old `<ctime>` header types. For example, the "system clock" class [has](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/to_time_t) [methods](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/from_time_t) for converting to and from the `<ctime>` time representation, `time_t`. This will be useful to you if you're combining C and C++ code, or need to expose a C interface somewhere; otherwise - try *avoiding* `<ctime>`-based code.

**C++20**

The new standard version approved in 2020 added:

- Time zones
- Calendars
- More Duration types
- More time point types
- More clocks

#### Beyond the standard: Howard Hinnant's Date libraries

As commenters @AndyG and @doug suggest, [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant) is *the* "C++ date&time guy", and much of his work has actually gone into the standard - but not all of it.

Howard maintains a library/set-of-libraries of his own, named "Date".

- [The "Date" library on GitHub](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)
- ["Date" library documentation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html)

It is based on C++11 `<chrono>`, but its changes are not exactly what's been added in C++20; so especially useful if you're using C++17 or earlier. It adds:

- Timezones
- Calendars, including Julian and Islamic
- More Duration types
- More time point types
- Weeks

I'm assuming that eventually, all the good stuff from here will get standardized, but that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @KaiserKatze: I thought GNU and LLVM already have all of C++20 implemented? For example, according to [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017) libstdc++ has these since July 2019.

Comment: See https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/issues/565 for a list of differences between Howard Hinnant's date lib and C++20.

Comment: I appreciate the effort that went into writing this answer. However, this type of answer is also why questions _Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more_ are off-topic.