# Recording how much time is required to run a portion of code and store it to an array in C++

Tags: c++, time, ctime

Need help in recording time taken to run several parts of code in C++. I need to store these times to an array for use later. In MATLAB I would do something like this;

```
for i=1 : n
    tic
    this is some stuff I want to run();
    array[1,i] = toc;
   
    tic
    this is some other stuff I want to run();
    array[2,i] = toc;
end
```

The above would run 2 different things n times and store the time taken to individually run those things into a 2-D array.

Is there something equivalent in C++?

Comment: Look at the [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library in C++11 and later, in particular [`std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock/now), [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), [`duration_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast), etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock/now) to get the current time (tic in your exemple).

You can find more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27856440/3314140).

For a 2d array, a simple [`std::array<T, n>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) where `T` is some kind of [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) should do the trick.

Comment: `std::array<std::array<std::chrono::milliseconds, N>, 2>` (or just `std::chrono::milliseconds[2][N]`) or equivalent should suffice.

Comment: I feel that if the answer relies heavily an another answer, the proper course of action should have been to flag as duplicate.